# The password validation sends out the wrong output?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char, passwords

The program that I've written is giving me the wrong output. It verifies whether the input password is 6 characters long with letters and numbers, if one of the requirement is not met, then it should say "Invalid Password." Otherwise, then it should output "Password Accepted." But when I enter more than 6 character long password, though the password is all letters, it still say password accepted.

```
import java.util.*;
public class passwd {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String in_pass;
        int i = 0, x = 0, l = 0, d = 0;
        boolean valid_len;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
        in_pass = in.next();
        int len = in_pass.length();
        valid_len = (len >= 6) ? true : false;
        char passwd_l;
        char passwd_d;
        if (valid_len == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");
        }
        else if (valid_len == true)
        {
            for (i = 0, x = 0; i < len; i++, x++)
            {
                passwd_l = in_pass.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLetter(passwd_l))
                {
                    l += i;
                }
                passwd_d = in_pass.charAt(x);
                if (Character.isDigit(passwd_d))
                {
                    d += x;
                }
            }
        } 
        if (i > 0 && x > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Password Accepted");
        } 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: If you are counting number of letter and digits, why you are not just increment l and d variable instead of l += i and d += x?? Your i and x variable will always be greater than 0 because they are incremented with every loop iteration.

Comment: `if (i > 0 && x > 0){System.out.println("Password Accepted");}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this one!

```
else if (valid_len == true){
       for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
              passwd_l = in_pass.charAt(i);
              if (Character.isLetter(passwd_l))
              {
                    l ++;
              }
              if (Character.isDigit(passwd_l))
              {
                    d ++;
              }
       }
} 
if (l > 0 && d > 0){
       System.out.println("Password Accepted");
}
```

Comment: Woah! Thanks! I have forgotten about the loop iteration, which increment the variables I've assigned. I just typed down the source code the way I see it in my head. Again, thank you so much.